# Query with value of field as part of condition

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this simple document setup:

- `dateAdded`: string with date format 'YYYY-MM-DD'
- `lastFetched`: Date object (`ISODate` in mongodb language)

```json
{
  lastFetched: 2021-03-01T09:27:07.406+00:00
  dateAdded:   "2020-12-19"
}
```

How can I find documents where `lastFetched` is smaller than `dateAdded`? Something like:

```js
db.collection.find( { lastFetched: {$lt: ISODate('$dateAdded')} } )
```

To do this I first need to convert either `lastFetched` to a date string, or `dateAdded` to an `ISODate` object.

But more importantly: how can I use the value of a field as input for a condition check? A simpler version would be:

```json
{
  lastFetched: "2021-03-01"
  dateAdded:   "2020-12-19"
}
```

With the following pseudo-query:

```js
db.collection.find( { lastFetched: {$lt: '$dateAdded'} } )
```

I already tried using `$addFields` (aggregate) as a first step:

```js
{
  date: ISODate('$dateAdded')
}
```

but that just gave me a date of `1970-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00`.

Any help would be very welcome!

Thanks

Comment: Check out the [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/#definition) operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to add an extra `$addFields` stage and in most cases it is best to minimize the number of stages.  You can convert to an `ISODate` in-line in the `$match` stage:

```js
db.foo.aggregate([
    {'$match': {'$expr': {
        '$lt': [{'$dateToString':{'date':'$lastFetched','format':'%Y-%m-%d'}},
                '$dateAdded'
               ]
    }}}
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Joe for the `$expr` tip. Here is the solution for future versions of myself:

Create the following aggregate stages. The first stage replaces the `ISODate` field `lastFetched` to a string version that matches the `dateAdded` format (YYYY-MM-DD). And then use `$expr` to check against that field.

```js
[
  {
    '$addFields': {
      'lastFetched': {
        '$dateToString': {
          'date': '$lastFetched', 
          'format': '%Y-%m-%d'
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$match': {
      '$expr': {
        '$lt': [
          '$lastFetched', '$dateAdded'
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```